# How To Use Shared Preference In This Todo App Code?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import 'colors.dart';
import 'todo_item.dart';
import 'todo.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Toodoo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Toodoo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Toodoo> createState() => _ToodooState();
}

class _ToodooState extends State<Toodoo> {
  final todosList = ToDo.todoList();
  List<ToDo> _foundToDo = [];
  final _todoController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();
String ""
  @override
  void initState() {
    _foundToDo = todosList;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => _key.currentState!.openDrawer(),
        ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff346594),
        title: const Text("ToDos", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: tdBGColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
              vertical: 15,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                searchBox(),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 50,
                          bottom: 20,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'All ToDos',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      for (ToDo todo in _foundToDo.reversed)
                        ToDoItem(
                          todo: todo,
                          onToDoChanged: _handleToDoChange,
                          onDeleteItem: _deleteToDoItem,
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    left: 20,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                    vertical: 5,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _todoController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Add a new todo item',
                        border: InputBorder.none),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 20,
                  right: 20,
                ),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _addToDoItem(_todoController.text);
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: tdBlue,
                    minimumSize: const Size(60, 60),
                    elevation: 10,
                  ),
                  child: const Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: const Navigation(),
    );
  }

  void _handleToDoChange(ToDo todo) {
    setState(() {
      todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
    });
  }

  void _deleteToDoItem(String id) {
    setState(() {
      todosList.removeWhere((item) => item.id == id);
    });
  }

  void _addToDoItem(String toDo) async{
    final sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      todosList.add(ToDo(
        id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
        todoText: toDo,
      ));
    });
    sp.setString(id, todo)
    _todoController.clear();
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<ToDo> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = todosList;
    } else {
      results = todosList
          .where((item) => item.todoText!
          .toLowerCase()
          .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }

    setState(() {
      _foundToDo = results;
    });
  }

  Widget searchBox() {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
  }
```

I am trying to save todo data locally, using shared preferences but don't know how to implement this, any help on this will be appreciated.Shared preferences is the best thing to use in such apps, so that's why I am using shared preference instead of firebase.

I have initialized Shared preferences in future but the thing is how to read and show the data with the controller given above the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Hive database](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) or [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to save such kind of data(Good practice).You should use `shared preference` to store small bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, shared preference is a good way to store data permanently on the local device. I can suggest you one way of doing this.

You need to create only one key (and value), and the value would be a stringified array. Every time user created new todo, you first need to pull the previous array, parse it to JSON, push the latest todo in that array, and set the key value again.

This array will also help you if you want to show the user all the todos by pulling the data only from one key, cause all the todos will the store in one array.

```dart
var todos = [
  {
    "id": "", 
    "todoText": "''"
  },
    {
    "id": "", 
    "todoText": "''"
  },
  ...
]
```

But you need to store stringified array, so you need to parse back to JSON after get data from shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences is a good idea when dealing with small data. example:

```
        // NB: you need to have shared_preferences in your packages (pubspec.yaml)
            class SharedPreferencesFunction{
            // save String, example: 'John', 'I love coding, it is fun' and so on
                 void saveString({required String key, required String value}) async {
                final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                await sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);
              }
            // save bool example: true, or false
              void saveBool({required String key, required bool value}) async {
                final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                await sharedPreferences.setBool(key, value);
              }
            // save int, numbers without points. like 1,50, 100 not 0.9, or
              //zero point other something(number)
              void saveInt({required String key, required int value}) async {
                final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                await sharedPreferences.setInt(key, value);
              }
            
              // save double, number with decimal point. like 9.0, 10.5, e.t.c
              void saveDouble({required String key, required double value}) async {
                final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                await sharedPreferences.setDouble(key, value);
              }
            
              // save List<String> a list of Strings. more like ['paul', 'john', 'jack'];
              void saveListOfString({
                required String key,
                required List<String> value,
              }) async {
                final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                await sharedPreferences.setStringList(key, value);
              }
            }
    
    Now to retrieve save this data you need to simply call that above method 
    like this: 
    
    
    class MyClass {
    // your other codes, 
    void saveString(String someValue){
       SharedPreferencesFunction().saveString(key:'learning', value: someValue);
    }
    // and others like that, according your data. // bool, int, double, 
     // List<String>, .... and so on 
    // remember to use this code according to your data type needs, but your data  // has to be (bool, String, int, double,List<String>) if you happen to have a // map and you want to save it, don't try to use the following code
    final Map<String, Object> info = {
    'name':'john',
    'age':'20',
    };
    // error 
    final String data = info.toString();
    // and save it like 
    saveString(data); // it is possible to save this data but you won't be able // to retrieve it for use later. 
    
    // instead use import 'dart:convert' show json;
    like  
    final String data = json.encode(info);
    // retrieve using json.decode
    }
    
    
    // finally retrieving data is simple
    
    class RetrieveData{
    void data()async{
    final sharedPref= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPref.getString('learning'); 
// this returns a String ? might be null if the value is absent 
    }
    }
```